# How can I debug private class fields in Node.js with VS Code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, encapsulation

How do I check the contents of the private fields of a class instance during runtime, debugging a Node app in VS Code?

It should be something basic but somehow seems not to be possible...

- VS Code's Javascript Debugger doesn't displays the private fields of objects
- I tried [`util.inspect`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v15.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options), but Node folks [decided to *not* make it work](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/27404).

If not possible, which are the workarounds?

I'm using:

- Node `15.3.0`
- VS Code `1.51.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

VS Code's built-in javascript debugger did not support debugging of private class fields at the time of this question. It does now, since version 1.56.0 (April 2021).

---

Old answer:

VS Code's built-in javascript debugger ([ms-vscode.js-debug](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.js-debug)) does not support private class fields yet. (there's a [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/issues/892) for it on github)

However, v8 does have a (currently in experimental state) [method for reading private class fields](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/v8/Runtime/#method-getProperties). I've made a proof of concept project ([leonardoraele/private-field-inspect](https://github.com/leonardoraele/private-field-inspect)) that uses Node's [inspector API](https://nodejs.org/api/inspector.html) to programatically open a debug session at runtime to read the contents of the variable. (this does not interrupt the runtime execution)

It works, but with a [few caveats](https://github.com/leonardoraele/private-field-inspect#caveats).

**Usage:**

```js
import inspect from '../path/to/private-field-inspect';

class Subject
{
    publicValue = 'not so secret';
    #secretValue = 'my secret';
}

const subject = new Subject();

inspect(subject)
    .then(console.debug);
```

**Output:**

```js
{ publicValue: 'not so secret', '#secretValue': 'my secret' }
```

---

The workaround above is not satisfactory for me, so I think it's better to avoid using private class fields if possible, until they are properly supported by debuggers. Instead, use Symbols to hide private variables.

**Example:**

```js
// my-class.js (or .msj)
const PRIVATE = {
    SECRET_VAL = Symbol('#secretVal');
};

export default class Subject {
    // ms-vscode.js-debug can read it, but other modules can't
    [PRIVATE.SECRET_VAL]: 'my secret';

    doSomething()
    {
        const secret = this[PRIVATE.SECRET_VAL];
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe VSCode has since shipped debugger support for private fields in April 2021's v1.56.1 release: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#v156-april-2021

Comment: Yes, they did! 

Comment: I have a 2022 build and I don't see them, what am I missing

 Version: 1.73.1 (Universal)
Commit: 6261075646f055b99068d3688932416f2346dd3b
Date: 2022-11-09T02:08:38.961Z
Electron: 19.0.17
Chromium: 102.0.5005.167
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.15-electron.0
OS: Darwin arm64 22.1.0
Sandboxed: No